Inconsistent orphan removal on ManyToMany with CascadeType.ALL
Hibernate 6 does not cascade REMOVE operation with @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) most of the time (due to BasicCollectionPersister.isCascadeDeleteEnabled always returning false) but seems to do so on that same collection mapped with @ManyToMany if cascading is started with an entity containing @OneToMany with orphanRemoval = true. Is this intended behavior?
I have distilled this into JUnit (Jupiter) test (see below). It sets up a "school" containing students (OneToMany) and students related (many-to-many) to teachers. The test shows that deleting teachers from a student does not affect the teachers but deleting students from a school (OneToMany) seems to actually delete teachers.
class CascadeDeleteOnManyToManyTest {
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private EntityTransaction transaction;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(CascadeDeleteOnManyToManyTest.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpEntityManager() {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDownEntityManager() {
        try {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        var sc = new School();
        entityManager.persist(sc);

        var s1 = new Student();
        var t1 = new Teacher();
        s1.teachers.add(t1); t1.students.add(s1);
        var t2 = new Teacher();
        s1.teachers.add(t2); t2.students.add(s1);

        var s2 = new Student();
        s2.teachers.add(t2); t2.students.add(s2);

        sc.students.add(s1); s1.school = sc;
        sc.students.add(s2); s2.school = sc;

        transaction.commit(); entityManager.clear(); transaction.begin();

        s1 = entityManager.find(Student.class, s1.id);
        s1.teachers.clear();

        transaction.commit(); // does NOT: delete from TEACHER where id=?
        entityManager.clear(); // aside: surprise: This makes a difference in emitted SELECTs later.
        transaction.begin();

        sc = entityManager.find(School.class, sc.id);
        sc.students.clear(); // does: delete from TEACHER where id=?

        transaction.commit();
        transaction.begin();

        t1 = entityManager.find(Teacher.class, t1.id);
        t2 = entityManager.find(Teacher.class, t2.id);
        assertNotEquals(null, t1);
        assertEquals(null, t2); // why?

        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Entity @Table(name = "SCHOOL")
    public static class School {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        long id;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "school")
        private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    @Entity @Table(name = "STUDENT")
    public static class Student {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        long id;

        @ManyToOne
        private School school;

        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_TEACHER", //
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID"), //
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TEACHER_ID"))
        private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    }

    @Entity @Table(name = "TEACHER")
    public static class Teacher {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        long id;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teachers")
        private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }
}

Just for completeness:
Here is the relevant fragment of the pom.xml:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.224</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

Here is the persistence.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="CascadeDeleteOnManyToManyTest">
        <class>playground.hibernate.CascadeDeleteOnManyToManyTest.School</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>

